# Ionic ion-modal height with keyboard bug

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, keyboard, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-popup

I have a ion modal which i want to show of 60% of my screen, but when keyboard appears the modal resizes to 60% of the screen (including keyboard) so it shrinks a lot. I want the modal to stay the same size (ideally the size of its contents). Pictures explain a lot.

This is the css

```
.ion-modal.modal {
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 0 !important;
  height: 60% !important;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

And this the html

```
<ion-modal-view id="details_modal" class="ion-modal">
STUFF
</ion-modal-view>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have this     <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, height=device-height" /> in your index ?

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik this ihe meta i have, it is the same except the minimum scale.     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, height=device-height, width=device-width">
 tried with yours still same problem

Comment: Your problem is when keyboard shows , Your device height get reduced.And than your modal is taking 60% of that decreased height. maybe change it into px . and see what happens?

Comment: Hi @Ujjwalkaushik i am aware that that is the problem, however is there a way the the device height is not affected by keyboard?I dont want fixed pixels because this should work in very different devices.

Comment: @Ujjwal kaushik thanks man, i've resolved this issue using --height:264px instead of --height:40%.

Comment: Changing % to px as suggested by @Ujjwalkaushik fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using `<ion-content overflow-scroll="false"></ion-content>`

> overflow-scroll="false"

fix the issue for me.